# Can not get statics files

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, express, static-files

I am trying to add Jquery-ui datetime picker in my express js application but I got a 404 error.

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepick"></p>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="stylesheets/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ > <script
src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script> <script
src="javascripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepick").datepicker(); }) 
</script>
```

this is my code, the statics files are in public javascripts and stylesheets under public folder.

NOTE: express code

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

EDIT1: console error

```
GET /historicos/javascripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js 404 2.263 ms - 948
```

firefox error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/historicos/stylesheets/jquery.datetimepicker.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 15ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/historicos/javascripts/jquery.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 28ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/historicos/javascripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 26ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/historicos/javascripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]
ReferenceError: $ is not defined historicos:25
```

Comment: You will have to show us your express code that serves these files.  node.js and Express do not serve any files by default.

Comment: Could you look at a dev console or in the error log on the server and tell us precisely what is giving you the 404?

Comment: updated wit the erros

Comment: You need to understand all the various absolute paths involved here.  What is `__dirname`?  What is the URL to the file that these script tags are in?  What is the actual directory hierarchy where these files are?  Why are you using relative paths to your scripts which can easily cause confusion and certainly are not necessary?

Comment: __dirname is an express variable that is related to the url for example localhost:3000/historicos, and the file hierarchy is public and inside it javascripts and stylesheets

Comment: You obviously have a path issue so I'm telling you that you need to look at the actual value of `__dirname` and construct all the various absolute paths in your head or on paper and figure out why they aren't matching up.  It is clear that something isn't what you think it is so you should look at what all the actual values are.  You could also set a breakpoint in `express.static()` and watch it actually compare the pathnames to see what isn't matching.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following file tree:

```
/root
    /public
        /stylesheets
        /javascripts
    server.js
```

**/root/server.js**

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Then:

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/jquery.datetimepicker.css
```

Now, if you want the url to be prefixed with **/historicos** you need to specify it as the first param of the **app.use()** function:

**/root/server.js**

```
 app.use('/historicos', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Now you can do this:

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/historicos/stylesheets/jquery.datetimepicker.css
```